# clauses and variables in Z3.py

Tags: z3, z3py

I'm working recently on Z3.py. I wonder If there is any way to display the number of clauses and variable of my model. I used to work on Alloy. Alloy displays these informations automatically. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: By model, I guess you mean set of assertions.
You can obtain statistics after a search has completed. 
The statistics include numbers, such as clauses and Boolean variables

Comment: Is there any command in Z3 to do these statistics automatically?  how can I see the CNF?